# Creating a type that can be used as a Func/method

Tags: c#, linq, types, expression

I have been playing around with [LINQ to Z3](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Bart-De-Smet-LINQ-to-Z3) for fun (not production use).

I've ended up with this syntax as a start:

```
var i = 123;
var test2 = from t in TheormProver.NewTheorm()
            let f = TheormProver.Func<int, bool>()
            let a = TheormProver.Int
            let g = TheormProver.Func<bool, int>()
            where !f(a * 2) && g(f(g(f(4)))) == i * a && a < g(f(a))
            select new { f = f.ToString(), g = g.ToString(), a, asd = "Test extra property" };

var solution = test2.Solve(); // Edited in for clarification
// note that test2 is a TheormProver<T> which has a "T Solve()" method defined.
```

The static `TheromProver.Int` and `TheormProver.Func` methods/properties simply return a basic type (as per their name) currently.

Moving forwards I want to make a sort of `Variable<T>` type that contains more information than just a value.

**TL;DR:** The problem I'm having is that I want `f` and `g` variables to be a custom type that I can add fields and properties to, **but** I still want to be able to use them with the syntax I've got in the where clause (i.e. as a method/`Func`).

So, **How do I create a custom type that can be used in method syntax while adding/having my own properties?**

Note that I don't care if calling the method does nothing, or doesn't work as I'll be manipulating the where clause so they'll never get invoked/executed.

---

**Example:**

```
var test2 = from t in TheormProver.NewTheorm()
            let f = TheormProver.Func<int, bool>()
            let a = TheormProver.Int
            where !f(a * 2) && a > 3 // f is used to create a method call expression
            select new { f , a };

var testSolution = test2.Solve();

var fSolution = testSolution.f; // F is its own type with unique properties/fields.

var fConstraints = fSolution.Constraints;

var fSomeProperty = fSolution.SomeProperty;

foreach(var constraint in fConstraints)
{
    //.....
}
```

I've mocked up a quick example of the work in progress syntax I have so far:

[http://liveworkspace.org/code/3Fm6JM$0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3Fm6JM%240)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class TheormProver
    {
        public static int Int { get { return default(int); } } // Really this would return my Variable<int>
        public static Func<T, TResult> Func<T, TResult>() { return default(Func<T, TResult>); } // Really this would return my Variable<Func<T, TResult>>

        protected List<Expression> Constraints; // Holds constraints / where clauses that get translated into the Z3 language

        //This gets called when we do the first "let" and gets us into the correctly typed world with a generic parameter
        public virtual TheormProver<T> Select<T>(Func<TheormProver, T> sel)
        {
            return new TheormProver<T>(Constraints);
        }
    }

    // This is what the user of the library sees and is returned by a from t in new TheormProver(). T will be the anonymous type from the last let
    class TheormProver<T> : TheormProver
    {
        public TheormProver(List<Expression> Constraints)
        {

        }

        // This gets called on subsequent "let"s, going from the anonymous type with one property "f" to one with 2, "f, g". Chaining this way allows as many lets as we want
        public virtual TheormProver<U> Select<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> sel)
        {
            return new TheormProver<T, U>(sel, Constraints.ToList());
        }

        public virtual TheormProver<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> constraint)
        {
            var result = (TheormProver<T>)this; // This should be a clone to allow composable queries

            result.Constraints.Add(constraint);

            return result;
        }

        public virtual T Solve(out bool foundSolution)
        {
            // TODO: Call Z3 and get a solution
            foundSolution = false;
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    internal class TheormProver<T, U> : TheormProver<U>
    {
        private LambdaExpression Selector;
        private TheormProver<T> InternalTheorumProver;

        public TheormProver(Expression<Func<T, U>> selector, List<Expression> constraints)
            : base(constraints)
        {
            Selector = selector;
            InternalTheorumProver = new TheormProver<T>(constraints);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = from t in new TheormProver()
                       let f = TheormProver.Func<int, bool>()
                       let g = TheormProver.Func<bool, int>()
                       let a = TheormProver.Int
                       where g(f(a)) == 0
                       select new { f, g, a };

            bool foundSolution;
            var testSolution = test.Solve(out foundSolution);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could show an example of what you are trying to achieve, even if that is not valid syntax.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, see my edit.

Comment: Why not create a type that has those properties and the func? `let f = new MyType(TheormProver.Func<int, bool>()) ... where !f.Func(a * 2)`

Comment: That will work as an alternative, but ideally I'd like to keep the where clauses as simple as possible. I like the simplicity of being able to do `f(g(a), g(123)) = 123` etc.

Comment: The only other alternative I've come up with is keeping `f` as a `Func` but having an extension method that they would use in the select that converts it to my special type for the purposes of getting the right return type for the select statement (similar to my current syntax with the `.ToString()`).

Comment: Yes, that would have been my next suggestion. However, I wonder about one thing: Where do the values come from for those properties? Who sets them? If setting them is not part of the query, the code that actually needs those properties could create the instance, i.e. the code that calls `Solve`.

Comment: The main type is the `TheormProver<T>`, where `T` is the type that's created in the select. This is what the type of `test2` is in the example. The `Solve` method is basically `T Solve()`, it creates and returns the type in the select statement. My problem is, if the select statement had `f` and it was just a `Func` then the `f` property of the anonymous type `T` would simply be a `Func`. I need the anonymous type to have the `f` property being my custom type, otherwise how do I return a strongly typed object with an `f` property of my custom type in my solve method?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Please try to answer this question: Where do the values for the properties `Constraints` and `SomeProperty` come from? Who sets them?

Comment: BTW: `test2` can't have a `Solve` method as it is an anonymous type, or am I missing something?

Comment: They get calculated by the `Solve` method, which creates a type instance of the `T` generic parameter. The `T` generic parameter is the anonymous type created by the final `select`. (`new { f, a }`). (Thanks for staying with this question!).

Comment: `test2` isn't a `T`, it's a `TheormSolver<T>`.

Comment: So LINQ to Z3 behaves differently than all the other LINQ implementations? Normally, the return type of a query is `IEnumerable<X>` where `X` is the type in the last select...

Comment: Yes, it behaves differently. It's pretty much abusing `Select` and `Where` method resolving. Like I say, not for production use. :)

Comment: But I agree with usr: You can't overload `()` and you can't derive a class from a delegate type, so you will have to find some workaround. A *very* hacky way would be to create an indexer in your custom type and make that internally call the delegate: `f[a * 2]`. But I really would advise against it.

Comment: Yeah, that is a hack to far! I'm also implicit casting to a `Func` wouldn't help either (if that's even possible). Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I think you could create a implicit conversion operator on your type. The problem is: Someone would have to trigger that conversion. It could work if you would pass the instance of your custom type to a method - that would trigger the conversion. Simply appending `()` however won't trigger it.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thinking (the `()` wouldn't be enough).

Comment: Perhaps you could integrate [the SSCCE code sample](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3Fm6JM$0) into the question

Comment: @sehe: Done, link and code included.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett thanks. That looks like a very well done SSCCE. Also, I agree, dynamics are not 'amenable' to it. Perhaps you can use some other way to 'associate meta-data' with your Func instances (perhaps use a Tuple or have class with implicit Userdefined Conversion to Func<>). This won't give you your syntax stability, but...

Comment: @sehe: The other thing about using `dynamic` is when I do something like `test2.Solve().f.MyMember` I don't get intellisense or anything as `f` is dynamic. I think I've got quite a few options now though, and will weigh them up. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a simple 'testbed' for your original code: [http://liveworkspace.org/code/3Bl7wC$0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3Bl7wC%240).

With, a bit of dynamic magic, you can have the following class as a drop-in replacement for `Func<T1, T2>`:

```
public class MyCallable<T1, T2> : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly Expression<Func<T1, T2> > _wrapped;
    private readonly Func<T1, T2> _compiled;

    public MyCallable(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> towrap) 
    { 
        _wrapped = towrap; _compiled = _wrapped.Compile(); 
    }

    public override bool TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        if ( (args.Length == 1) && 
             (args[0].GetType() == typeof(T1)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Invoking ""{0}"" on {1}", _wrapped, args[0]);
            result = _compiled((T1) args[0]);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //throw new ArgumentException("Cannot invoke " + _wrapped + " with the arguments passed");
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it defines you class as being "dynamic" and allows you to try and invoke it as if it were a delegate/function/... a general callable:

```
// in "TheormProver"
public static dynamic Func<T1, T2>() { return new MyCallable<T1, T2>(arg1 => default(T2)); }
```

Here's proof it works: **[http://liveworkspace.org/code/4kBypd$0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4kBypd%240)**

Output:

```
Invoking "arg1 => False" on 0
Invoking "arg1 => False" on 4
Invoking "arg1 => 0" on False
Invoking "arg1 => False" on 0
Invoking "arg1 => 0" on False
Invoking "arg1 => False" on 0
Invoking "arg1 => 0" on False
```

Full code for reference:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Dynamic;

public class Program
{
    public class MyCallable<T1, T2> : DynamicObject
    {
        private readonly Expression<Func<T1, T2> > _wrapped;
        private readonly Func<T1, T2> _compiled;

        public MyCallable(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> towrap) 
        { 
            _wrapped = towrap; _compiled = _wrapped.Compile(); 
        }

        public override bool TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
        {
            if ( (args.Length == 1) && 
                 (args[0].GetType() == typeof(T1)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Invoking ""{0}"" on {1}", _wrapped, args[0]);
                result = _compiled((T1) args[0]);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //throw new ArgumentException("Cannot invoke " + _wrapped + " with the arguments passed");
                result = null;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class TheormProver
    {
        public static object[] NewTheorm() { return new object[] { 1 }; }
        public static dynamic Func<T1, T2>() { return new MyCallable<T1, T2>(arg1 => default(T2)); }
        public static int Int { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = 123;
        var test2 = from t in TheormProver.NewTheorm()
            let f = TheormProver.Func<int, bool>()
            let a = TheormProver.Int
            let g = TheormProver.Func<bool, int>()
            where !f(a * 2) && g(f(g(f(4)))) == i * a && a < g(f(a))
            select new { f = f.ToString(), g = g.ToString(), a, asd = "Test extra property" };

        test2.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }

}
```

Comment: Very nice idea. Does it work as part of an expression tree? I'm not so familiar with dynamic.

Comment: Indeed a cool idea. I wasn't even aware that a dynamic object could behave like a delegate. But I see the same problem as usr: It most likely won't work correctly in expression trees because the whole code is only evaluated at runtime.

Comment: @usr I'm not sure what you mean by "as part of an expression tree". In general, the answer is "yes": it is just normal usage of the DLR. However, if you mean, is it strong typed at the expression level, the answer is "no". This is the nature of 'dynamic': it's late bound, however you get the full benefit of proper overload resolution, extension method resolution, user defined conversions and other things that don't work in 'normal' C# generics.

Comment: As I understand it the OP is picking apart the IQueryable he gets to generate Z3 terms. He needs the same ability when working with dynamic in this case. Not sure if you can use dynamic as part of an `Expression`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I agree. The limitations you mentioned were explicitely not requirements in the question, though. The question focused fully on 'function invocation' syntax compatibility, AFAICS

Comment: @sehe: Most likely "as part of an expression tree" meant: Can it be analyzed without being executed? Because that's what most of the time is the reason for using `Expression<Func<...>>` instead of `Func<...>`. See LINQ to SQL translation.

Comment: @sehe: I don't want to "destroy" your answer by this discussion, but I think the possibility of analyzing the tree is important. I quote: "Note that I don't care if calling the method does nothing, or doesn't work as I'll be manipulating the where clause so they'll never get invoked/executed". I still think that your answer is a very elegant solution in the more general sense - I am just not sure it will work in the Z3 context. And note the `expressions` tag :)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I don't see the OP using Expression<> anywhere. I'm only using it for "pretty" debug tracing myself :) Also, obviously dynamics **can** be used in expression trees. However, it won't have the same performance characteristics of strong typing guarantees. If need be, some of that may explicitely be coded for, but in that case I heartily suggest not leaving the 'strong typed' domain at all, all just to get "syntactic sugar"

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Good point about the "don't care if calling the method does nothing" part. I'd have to think about why I don't understand this approach on an intuitive level. I have a feeling there are better ways to achieve what the OP seems to be doing, then. Maybe I'll think about it some more.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, sehe: I'll try and create an example of the classes / method declarations I'm using to give you a better idea. Basically I'm using `Where`'s and `Select`'s that accept `Expression<Func<>>`s and I'm returning `TheormProver<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>/IQueriable<T>`. The solve method manipulates the where and select expressions to return an instance of the `T`.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett (I did obviously realize that you weren't returning "IEnumerables". That was just me mocking up the minimum amount of code to _compile the syntax_, as your question was about _that_: maintaining syntax compatibility. Like I said, I have the intuition that either (a) the syntactic sugar isn't worth the problems if you need to stay in early-bound domain (b) or you should go "fully dynamic" compiling the expression from _source text_ when constructing your expression trees)

Comment: Ok, this won't do anything, but gives you all the key types and methods. http://liveworkspace.org/code/3Fm6JM$0

Answer (score 1):

You can't add custom members to delegate types and you cannot overload `operator ()` in C#. That leaves you with extension methods.

Now, you don't want to add extensions to very general delegate types like `Func<int, int>` because that pollutes the namespace. I suggest you create custom delegates like this:

```
delegate TResult Z3Func<T1, TResult>(T1 arg1);
```

Then you can add extensions to `Z3Func`.

The extension calls will end up as static method calls in the expression tree you are analyzing.

Comment: As long as the extension method on the general Func is not in a generally used namespace, I don't think intellisense pollution is a problem.

Comment: Why was this accepted so quickly? I'm still writing an answer that actually works with unmodified syntax. Hang on 5 minutes

Comment: @sehe: Now you got me interessted.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Just posted it

Comment: @sehe: Unaccepted. I'll leave it open for a day or two to give more chance for better answers.