# Difference between Query Expression and Method Expression in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I don't know whether the term of above title is appropriate.

Just like `a` and `b`:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);

var a = from l in list
        where l % 2 == 0
        select l;
var b = list.Where(l => l % 2 == 0);
```

When should I use each of them? And any difference?

Comment: It's the same.  First one is called LINQ expression, second - lambda expression

Comment: @realnero Actually, the question's title is correct. Query syntax expression vs method syntax expression.

Comment: To complement the answers below - if you use a tool such as [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/), you can input this code yourself and run it, and then look at the IL-compilated code. It'll be exactly the same code for both statements. =)

Comment: As an asside, note that you could make a class with the correct `Select`, `Where` etc. methods (but not an `IQueriable`) and it could be used with query syntax and the methods would get called. See here for an interesting example of doing that: http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/tags/Z3/default.aspx and a question I had about setting it up nicely here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566240/creating-a-type-that-can-be-used-as-a-func-method

Answer (score 22, accepted):

None, Query expression compiles into Method expression.

[Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx)

> Because queries return an IEnumerable, you compose them in method
>   syntax by chaining the method calls together. This is what the
>   **compiler does behind the scenes when you write queries by using query syntax**

Also see: [LINQ Query Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx)

> **At compile time, query expressions are converted to Standard Query Operator method calls** according to the rules set forth in the C#
>   specification. Any query that can be expressed by using query syntax
>   can also be expressed by using method syntax. However, in most cases
>   query syntax is more readable and concise. For more information, see
>   C# Language Specification and Standard Query Operators Overview.

Apart from that one place where I have found something that can't be done in Query expression is to get the index along with the item. For example you can do following in method syntax:

```
var result = list.Select((r,i) => new { value = r, index = i});
```

In query expression an external variable has to be defined to achieve this purpose. Here is a similar discussion with [answer from Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/269070/961113)

Answer (score 6):

### No

There is no difference between them.

From [`Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx)

> Because queries return an IEnumerable, you compose them in method
>   syntax by chaining the method calls together. **This is what the
>   compiler does behind the scenes when you write queries by using query
>   syntax.** And because a query variable does not store the results of the
>   query, you can modify it or use it as the basis for a new query at any
>   time, even after it has been executed.

Also from [`LINQ Query Expressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx)

> **At compile time, query expressions are converted to Standard Query
>   Operator method calls.**

Answer (score 3):

Query expression is transformed into standard method calls by compiler.

```
var a = from l in list
        where l % 2 == 0
        select l;

var b = list.Where(l => l % 2 == 0);
```

These two are exactly the same in compiled code.

However, not all methods have a keyword associated in query expression syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference, it's a matter of personal preference. You can even mix the two styles if you want to.

The Linq keywords are translated into the method call syntax by the C# compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The difference, in fact, is no.
In fact, it is one and the same thing, except that the expression for the $a$ the compiler converts to an expression equivalent to expression for $b$.