# Is there any difference between sql linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Pieces. I want an int[] of PieceID;

I try this, but this create an anonymous type[].

```
PiecesTop1 = new List<Piece>();

var test = PiecesTop1.Select(x => new {x.PieceID}).ToArray();
```

Then I found this syntaxis and works ok.

```
var lstPieceID = from p in PiecesTop1
                 select p.PieceID;

int[] arrPieceID = lstPieceID.ToArray();
int i = arrPieceID[0];
```

I usually use first sintaxis so not familiar with second one.

- First question: How I make first sql to return an int[].
- Second question: How can I call each of those sql query type to difference beetween them?
- Is there any diference on what sintaxis should I use (just in case I'm not using any  database).

Comment: To return an `int[]` instead of anonymous type array use `var test = PiecesTop1.Select(x => x.PieceID).ToArray();`

Comment: @Habib Thanks for your comment. But even when `Difference between Query Expression and Method Expression in LINQ` solve question two and three, my main question was regarding the returning select.

Comment: I tried to answer that question in my comment, I am sure there is a duplicate for that *particular* question as well on Stackoverflow, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @Habib Yes, and you answer work great. I'm just tought wasn't ok mark my question duplicate for the secondary questions. But dont worry issue is  already solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test = PiecesTop1.Select(x => x.PieceID).ToArray();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer all the questions.

Comment: @CriketerOnSO Is ok, this answer first question. Other two I got a duplicated question link to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677958/difference-between-query-expression-and-method-expression-in-linq)