# In Linq, is a SELECT required when WHERE is used?

Tags: c#, linq

If you have a Linq statement that uses a WHERE clause, for example:

```
var result = someCollection.Where(x => x.value > 5).Select(x => x);
```

Is the SELECT required, or is it redundant? It appears that I can safely omit the SELECT if I'm not trying to get at an object property, but am not sure if this is proper...

Comment: Select is redundant you can remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case No, it is not required, since you are selecting the object. So you can have:

```
var result = someCollection.Where(x => x.value > 5);
```

as far as better practice is concerned, I would remove the redundant code.

But, if you are going to select a specific property then that could be useful, like:

```
var result = someCollection.Where(x => x.value > 5)
                   .Select(x=> x.SomeSpecificProperty);
```

One more thing to add, with query expression you will need the select.

```
var result = from x in someCollection
             where x.Value > 5
             select x;
```

but at compile time the above query expression will be converted to Method Expression, *without  `Select`.*

Comment: Ah, I think that was where my confusion came from... that there is a difference between query and lambda syntax.  Thanks.

Comment: @newmanth, yes there is *only* the difference in syntax, otherwise query expression compiles into method expression. You can read more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677958/difference-between-query-expression-and-method-expression-in-linq)

Answer (score 0):

It's redundant. `Select` is more like the functional `map` (see JavaScript, Haskell, Ruby). If you aren't going to transform the input object into a different form than it is currently in, there's no need to use `Select`.

Answer (score 0):

> In Linq, is a SELECT required when WHERE is used?

No, it isnt.

Answer (score 0):

No... is not necessary this time... may be if you want to select a new object different than "someCollection" it will be necessary

something like:

```
var result = someCollection.Where(x => x.value > 5).Select(x => new ObjName() { name = x.name, lastname = x.lastname });
```